# How to return the processed form data to the template without saving it to the database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am making an English grammar checker. I have two models Sentence and Error. The user will input a sentence in the form and the errors (if any) will be generated and attached to the sentence programatically. Now I have two types of users: free and paid. I don't want to save the results to the database for the free accounts. How can I display the results in the template without saving them to the database?

```
# noting gets displayed in the template with this code
...
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SentenceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            form.save(commit=False)
            sent_str = cd['sent']
            s = Sentence(sent=sent_str, sent_correct=sent_str)
            s.author = user
            # s.save(commit=False) --- This line throws an error
            if user.is_basic or user.is_standard or user.is_premium:
                s.save()
            sent = nlp(sent_str)
            sents = []
            subjs = [t for t in sent if t.dep_ in subj_ls]
            two_subj = False
​
            if len(subjs) >= 2:
                two_subj = True
​
            if not subjs:
                has_imp_patt = imp_patt(sent)
                if has_imp_patt:
                    pass
                else:
                    print('Line 60')
                    msg = '<span style="color:#be0000">Subject\\verb not found</span>'
                    m = Message(msg=msg, sent=s)

                    if user.is_basic or user.is_standard or user.is_premium:
                        m.save()
                    form = SentenceForm()
                    return render(request, 'home.html', {'sentences': sentences, 'form': form})
...
```

Comment: It is in `form.cleaned_data`: this is a dictionary-like object with the values. So you can pass that to the context to render data.

Comment: I also tried to return the variable s in the context dictionary and accessing it the template. It didn't display anything.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Is it possible to add additional key-value pairs to cleaned_data?

Comment: yes its possible. `cleaned_data` is a dictionary